# Why should I use Docker Secrets?

Tags: docker, docker-secrets

For the last few months I've managed passwords for my docker containers by putting them in the ENV variables.

Example:

```
web:
  environment:
    - PASSWORD=123456
```

Then I bumped into Docker Secrets. So my questions are:

1. Which are the reasons why I should use them?
2. Are they more secure? How?
3. Can you provide a simple example to show their functionalities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on a use case.

If you're running one application on your own machine for development that accesses just one secret, you don't need docker secrets.

If you're running dozens of machines in production with a dozen of clustered services all requiring secrets for each other, you do need the secret management.

Apart from security concern, it's just plain easier to have a standardized way of accessing, creating and removing your secrets.

Answer (score 0):

a basic `docker inspect` (among other things) will show all your environment variables, so this is not secure at all.

You can also have a look at

keywhiz

square.github.io/keywhiz

or vault

hashicorp.com/blog/vault.html

Answer (score 0):

From:  https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/13490

- **Environment Variables.** Environment variables are discouraged, because they are:

  - Accessible by any proces in the container, thus easily "leaked"
  - Preserved in intermediate layers of an image, and visible in docker inspect
  - Shared with any container linked to the container